# compatibility issue in firefox, dynamic,absolute table content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

How to make this (http://jsbin.com/uxayid/3/) work in firefox too?

This is the css of the triangles:

```
#c table tr td {
    height: 295px;
    width: 208px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.tr-topright {
    border-left-width: 42px;
    border-top-width: 42px;
    border-left-color: white;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #BBBBBB;
    border-top-style: solid;
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 6px 0 lightGrey;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

The first one is the expected result.

[image: chrome and firefox preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

to the

```
#c table tr td
```

rule

and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you it works. Could you tell my how did you find out this?

Comment: @2astalavista: I noticed that all (in your example 4) the top right corner elements (<span> tabs) where stacking on top of each other at the top right corner of the table. That told me that the box model was not enforced for the contents of the TD elements. Display: block did that. Effectively it instructed the <span> element to honor the boundaries of it container. The float: left was added to allow your design to be maintained.